# Destrucción de variables de sesión PHP / APACHE

Tags: php, apache

¿Cómo puedo destruir todas las sesiones o childNodes con un botón?

Tengo un sistema que trabaja con variables de sesión, cuando hago cambios importantes al sistema aviso a todos para que cierren y vuelvan a abrir, pero hay algunas personas que no lo hacen. Entonces requiero una función que destruya todas las sesiones activas y obligue por sistema a entrar de nuevo.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Gracias

Answer (score 3):

Las variables de sesión de php se guardan en session.save_path, así que depende de cada servidor. Lo único que tendrías que hacer es borrar el contenido de ese directorio.

```
# find your session path in php
php -r 'echo session_save_path();'

cd /var/lib/php5/sessions

# remove session files
rm sess_*

# or with find
find . -name "sess_*" -print -delete
```

Fuente: 
https://blog.chemel.fr/apache-destroy-all-php-sessions/

Podrias tambien crear un script que obtenga el path y borre el contenido. Obtenes el setting de php ini y lo borras con php, pero tal vez es mas fácil hacer un archivo bash.

Comment: Buena opción, otra forma de hacerlo seria crear un token común a todas las sesiones, en un archivo o en la bd, y comprobarlo en las peticiones, si el token no coincide mandar a login.

Answer (score 0):

En principio debería ser sencillo. Crea una función con el siguiente contenido y llámala cuando la necesites.

```
session_unset();
session_destroy();
```

Indica la localización donde quieres que se redirija tras deslogear.

```
header("location:/");
exit();
```

Comment: Eso eso afecta a la sesión actual no a todas las sesiones que es lo que pide el.

Comment: pudiste resolver amigo?

Comment: yo tengo esa misma duda